# Serialization for a list of ffdf objects

Tags: r, serialization, memory-management, bigdata

I have a list, `Z`, where each `Z[[i]]` is an `ffdf` object.

My question is how to save `Z` to disk for future sessions, perhaps using something like `save.ffdf`.

```
Z <- list()
for(i in 1:10) {
  Z[[i]] <- as.ffdf(data.frame(array(1,dim=c(2,10))))
}

is(Z[[1]])
is(Z)
```

Comment: why not simply use `save(Z, file="Z.Rdata")`... worked fine when I tried it?!

Comment: @holzbrn Because the ff file is saved in a temp directory and will get erased. After you re-`load` `Z.Rdata` try typing `Z[[1]]` and you'll get something such as `opening ff C:/Users/..../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpO47OSM/ffdf5645baa5ac8.ff`.

Comment: Ah, ok! I just restarted the session, not the computer! Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffsave()` to save a list of objects, but it expects a list of names that can be resolved in the current environment. However, you can write your own helper function put each object (df) in the list into a a variable and the use ffsave to save these objects. Something like this:

```
saveList <- function(lst, fname) {
    outlist = c()
    for (i in 1:length(lst))  {
        name = paste0('out_',i)
        outlist = c(outlist, name)
        assign(name, lst[[i]])
    }
    ffsave(list=outlist, file=fname)
}
```

When you load this file with `ffload()` you will get a bunch of objects names out_1, out_2, ... in your current environment. You probably don't want this, so you need another helper function to put the things back into a list:

```
loadList <- function(fname) {
    ffload(fname)
    objs = ls(pattern="out")
    outlist = list()
    for (o in objs) {
        idx= as.integer( strsplit(o,"_")[[1]][2] )
        outlist[[idx]] = get(o)
    }
    outlist
}
```

Note: the source code has to be modified/extended if you want to use names instead of numeric index values.

Comment: I get the error `Error in system(cmd, input = filelist, intern = TRUE) : 'zip' not found` when using `saveList`

Comment: That's a problem in `ffsave()`; it uses `zip` to compress its files. If you do not have `zip` on your path you get this error.

Comment: What do you mean by "zip on your path"?

Comment: `zip` is command line tool for create ZIP files. In order for ff to use it, it has to be installed and in a directory that is in the search path (PATH environment variable). I think the correct version of zip for Windows can be downloaded here: http://www.info-zip.org/  But I could be wrong (I am using Linux...).  If you need more instructions search for "ffsave zip windows" and you will find people with the same problem (+ solutions... I think ...)

Comment: I now get the following error with the saveList function:  `[99] "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiWcDBa/ffdf17385057488.ff" 
[100] "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiWcDBa/ffdf173865264183.ff" 
Error in ffsave(list = outlist, file = fname, rootpath = "C://RTools//bin") : 
  the previous files do not match the rootpath (case sensitive)`

Comment: Does `ffsave` work by itself? Can you save a single data.frame with it? Did you specify the rootpath yourself and if yes, have you tried without?